# How to solve this Fatal error: Interface 'Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface' not found in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, fatal-error

> When I go to Magento admin,it shows fatal error. This is the
>   screenshot of my error

[image]

Please guide me how to get rid of this.

Comment: In which Magento version you get this error ?

Comment: Did you created any module recently which uses observer?

Comment: magento-2.1....

Comment: Yes, I will create module for change custom price of cart item through observer @SukumarGorai .

Comment: Can you disable it and check? If it works then user the events under frontend.

Comment: I will removed this module,after that it also show fatal error. @SukumarGorai

Comment: Did you run setup upgrade, di compile and static content deploy after module remove?

Comment: When I run setup upgrade,setup di compile,setup static-content deploy command,it show error. @SukumarGorai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86260/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-lovely-setia).